# Contract Bridge Better minors

Tags: bridge, bidding

Using better minor convention partner open one club, and I have five diamonds with three honors. I answer two diamonds to show the diamonds. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

No, playing a *natural* system such as [**Goren**](http://www.duralbridge.com/goren.ing.htm) or [**Two Over One**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2/1_game_forcing) the *jump shift* response into a new suit shows about 17-18 points in addition to the good suit. You have the good suit but (at time of writing) not the requisite overall hand strength. If the suit being bid is not at least 5 cards in length then the bid must also show 4+ card support in Opener's suit..

In addition to the above the bid announces that:
- The opponents shall not be allowed to play undoubled;
- Slam will be bid if a fit is found and sufficient controls are present.

It is because of the first point above that the bid should be made on HCP rather than playing strength. Good suits with playing strength but less defence can make a delayed jump shift, a delayed jump raise, or a delayed jump rebid. These now **deny** sufficient defensive strength for the initial *jump shift*. The *jump shift* response must ***never*** be made with a two suited hand unless the second suit is Opener's first bid suit.

When partner opens 1C it is very likely (especially playing a **Strong 1 NT**) that partner intends to rebid either 1 or 2 NT. Narrowing the *jump shift* response to slam going hands leaves more room for additional exploration below game, which will not only improve any NT games stumbled into but also find more good minor suit slams.

Comment: A [Strong jump shift](http://www.bridgebum.com/strong_jump_shifts.php) is more likely to show 17+ than 20+, depending on system and partnership agreement

Comment: @DavidSiegel: While I take your point, why not link to an[ actual expert's opinion](http://www.rpbridge.net/3b00.htm)?

Comment: While I like Pavlicek's writing, that page, while including a strong jump-shift as part of the structure does not describe it in any detail, and I find the Bridge bum site well worth using as a reference.

Comment: @DavidSiegel: I have concerns about the author's competence, as that one page is particularly badly written. It suggests that a han with a longest suit of 5 cards can be one-suited; it cannot. It can be three suited (5440) or two suited(5431 or 5422) or balanced (5332) but a hand must have a 6-card or longer suit to be one suited. That kind of imprecision can ruin partnerships. It is also frequently wise to jump shift in a 4-card suit when holding 4-card support for partner and requisite strength., which I don't see described at all.

Answer (score -2):

### **No.**

Playing [Standard American](http://www.duralbridge.com/SAYC.ing.htm) or [Two-over-one](http://www.duralbridge.com/twooverone.ing.htm) the classic agreement is to play [strong jump shifts](http://www.bridgebum.com/strong_jump_shifts.php) in a non-competitive auction. In that case a 2D bid after a 1C opening would show not only a 5-card suit including at least 5 HCP, but also at least 17 points in the overall hand. Such a bid is forcing to game.

However, many of the stronger players now prefer to play [Weak Jump Shifts](http://www.bridgebum.com/weak_jump_shifts.php) in which a bid of 2D over an opening 1C would show a **6-card** suit, and 2-5 HCP in the total hand. Over such a bid, opener usually passes or bids the final contract. A bid of 2NT is forcing and asks the responded to further describe his hand.

Playing SA or 2/1, a bid of 1D over 1C often indicates a 5-card suit. With a 4-card or longer major, the responder will usually bid the major unless the diamonds are significantly better, **and** the hand is strong enough to reverse by bidding the major later. Therefore only hands which are 3-3 or shorter in the majors (or rather strong hands) will bid 1D. Many (but far from all) such hands have 5+ cards in the diamond suit. Therefor opener should be prepared for a 5-card diamond suit, and responder does not need to jump to show it, unless the hand suits the partnership agreement for a jump-shift, weak or strong.  If the bidding has gone 1C-pass-1D, the responder will probably rebid Diamonds later to show such a good suit as 5-cards with three honors. Remember that as a new-suit bid from an unpassed responder, 1D is forcing 1 round.

To anyone thinking that "Standard American" should include 4-card major systems, and so this answer should have discussed such alternatives: that was once the case, but has not been for several decades. No North American tournement or club player describing a system as "Standard American" will mean a 4-card major system. This has been true since not long after the final edition of *Goren's Bridge Complete* came pout in the early 1980s with the Goren system fully reworked on a 5-card major basis. There is a case to eb made that a 4-card major system is better in many cirumstsancecs. But what ever one might call such a system, it isn't "Standard American" (much less SAYC), and it isn't common in NA duplicate play.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93198/discussion-on-answer-by-david-siegel-contract-bridge-better-minors).

Comment: Please keep discussion of required downvote comments in the linked chat room. Your comment was there for two months; you're not going to get any new responses from people who downvoted your post.

Comment: @murgatroid99 I do not use the chatrooms here. Ever. I find they serve only to hide possibly useful information, and have an unhelpful interface. I object to my comments being removed to a chatroom.  But since that comment did not directly relate to the answer, I will refrain from reinstating it.

Comment: If there was anything that was both useful and relevant in those comments, it should be turned into an edit to the answer itself. All other comments do not belong here on the post. I was trying to be helpful by moving them to the chat room to preserve them in some form so that the discussion can continue if you want, but you are free to act as though the comments were simply deleted.